# Trying to Mount external USB drive with NTFS partition in WSL, I get error 19

Tags: mount, ntfs, windows-11, wsl2

I'm Trying to mount an NTFS partition in WSL. But when I'm following the procedure described in [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk)

```
wsl --mount <DiskPath> --partition 2
```

in wsl I get the following error:

```bash
ERROR: Mount:2860: mount(/dev/sdd2, /share/PHYSICALDRIVE1p2, ntfs, 0x0, ) failed 19
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To mount an NTFS partition drive in WSL, following steps are working for me

```
wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 --bare
```

in wsl, check the partition number

```bash
lsblk
```

then

```bash
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
sudo mount /dev/sdd2 /mnt/g
```

Wish it could be clearer in the Docs!
*Note* that could have poor performance, as stated in this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6985)

Comment: Note that this WON'T work if you use a partition on your boot drive for some insane reason.